# Saving to multiple locations in Python

Tags: python, csv, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a job that scrapes and saves it to a `.csv` file.

I want to transfer a `.csv` file to 18 separate locations.  Is there an easier way to do this in Python?  I have tried the below code:

```
src_dir = "C:/AA.csv"
dst_dir1 = "C:/A"
dst_dir2 = "C:/B"
dst_dir3 = "C:/C"
dst_dir4 = "C:/D"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(src_dir):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith('.csv'):
            shutil.copy(os.path.join(root,f), dst_dir, dst_dir1, dst_dir2)
```

Comment: Are you trying to copy `C:/AA.csv` to the multiple directories `dst_dirx`?

Comment: And if you do, walking over the csv file won't bring much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy a file to multiple locations the following should work:

```
import os
import shutil

dst_dirs = ["C:/A", "C:/B", "C:/C", "C:/D"]
src_file = "C:/AA.csv"
for d in dst_dirs:
    shutil.copy(src_file, d)
```